# Is it safe to compile one source with SSE2 another with AVX architecture?

Tags: visual-c++, sse, intrinsics, avx

I'm using AVX intrinsics, but since for everything other than _mm256 based intrinsics MSVC generates non-vex instructions, I need to compiler the whole source code with /arch:AVX. The rest of the project is compiled with /arch:SSE2, so that it works on older CPUs and I'm manually checking if AVX is available.

The source containing AVX code (compiled for AVX) includes a huge library of templates and other stuff, just to have the definitions. Is there a possibility that the compiler/linker decides to instantiate some template with AVX instructions, just because it has been included in this source as well? In that case it would make it crash on non-AVX processors

Comment: You'd better not share C++-ish stuff between modules with different compile options, lest you violate the one-definition rule.  Treat it like you would a DLL, using plain C interfaces to cross the boundary, except that the various modules don't have their own namespaces for extern linkage, so your ability to use C++ inside is also constrained.

Comment: I created a test project hoping to answer your question, but it's not behaving as I'd expected (templates seems to be instantiated thought they don't need to)... I should answer this in a few hours, OR maybe open a new (bit different) question about it...

Comment: Thank you folks. The thing is, I'd do the classic "C" thingy if it would be possible/easy, but it's just dependent on lots of definitions and stuff, so it's quite problematic. And all that mess just because the compiler doesn't have any way to specify that I want "vex" instructions... @Marc.2377 please let me know what you find out.

Comment: Of course. Btw, are you compiling via command line, or using Visual Studio?

Comment: Both. And also on Mac via LLVM, and also trying Intel Compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that the compiler/linker decides to instantiate
> some template with AVX instructions, just because it has been included
> in this source as well?

Yes, it may happen, as seen in my [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29380336/3258851). Check out the (other) good answers given there.

My preferred workaround was to modify the template to include a discriminative parameter, but it may be too much of a hassle if it's really a "huge library", just like using global definitions as you mentioned [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380675/3258851).